# Random selection in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am a beginner .. I need some help to write a formula in Excel to randomly select people to 6 teams based on gender for example:

I have a list of 78 people containing 48 females and 30 males and I want to distribute them on 6 teams but each team has to have 5 males not more or less.

I have tried using different formulas that pick up a name randomly based on one criteria but it ends up getting duplicates or errors, same for randomly picking names with no criteria

here is an example of my list:

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Voting to reopen as this is not nearly as broad as anticipated.  The answers serve as a good canonical basis for duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

Random Picking with `VLOOKUP()` or so is difficult if you want to avoid duplicates. My approach would be to add a random number into an extra column (`=RND()`), and then simply sort the data lines by the random values. Then just take the top N.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formulaic version of *Aganju*'s approach.  Put the names in **A1** through **A30**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

and copy down.  In **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$30,MATCH(LARGE($B$1:$B$30,ROW()),$B$1:$B$30,0))
```

and copy down.  Column **C** will be a scrambled version of column **A**.  Just pick **C1** through **C5** for the first team, **C6** through **C10** for the second team, etc.:

[image]